# Building Objective-C App with External Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am integrating [growl](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php?lang=cocoa) into my Objective-C app.

However If I build and run my app without copying the Growl.framework to **~/Library/Frameworks** or a corresponding location then my App fails to execute.

I don't really fully understand Frameworks under objective-c, but I was wondering if there is anyway to include the Framework within my App so I don't have to manually distribute the framework to the user?

I believe that's what [tweetweet](http://github.com/zmalltalker/tweettweet/tree/master) does in there build process but I haven't quite figured out how they did it.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in your target in Xcode you need to create a new 'Copy Files' build phase (right click on the target > Add > New Build Phase > New Copy Files Build Phase). When the More Info window pops up, click on the pop up button and choose Frameworks. Drag this build phase to just below the copy resource phase and then drag any frameworks you want copied over to it.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Not really sure how I over looked that.