# xCode 4 import Framework doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode4

I have added the objection Framework to my project via linked binaries.
Now I am trying to import a file form this framework

```
#import <Objection/Objection.h>
```

But the compiler says: Objection/Objection.h not found!

I tried everything,
other linker flags are set to -ObjC and -all_load
Framework search Paths are set to the correct directory
The Library is linked within the project

So what else could be the problem?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Objection framework is built for iOS the framework is called 'Objection-iOS.framework'. Ergo the import would look something like this:

```
#import <Objection-iOS/Objection.h>
```

Comment: I've built the framework for iOS, and my import is correct, yet I still have the same issue as @Alexander

Comment: Are you using the framework? If you are integrating the Objection project directly the steps are much different. You'll have to add Objection-StaticLib as a target dependency and link the static lib to the target. You'll have to then set the header search path to $(SRCROOT)/Path/To/Objection/Headers. This is why I made it a framework in the first place because there are any number of ways to mess up this process. There isn't any way to mess up the framework unless you haven't linked to it.

Comment: I should have followed up after I got it working, but yes, I'm sure that I'm using the framework. The only way I could get it working with my project was to put the Objection framework in $(SRCROOT). I had been trying $(SRCROOT)/External. I'm also using an Xcode workspace. Never tried a non-workspace variant to see if my issues were related to that. I'm a novice iOS developer, so maybe I'll come to understand the benefits of distributing a framework. But by comparison, getting Kiwi working was much easier and less error prone despite the manual steps.

Comment: Interesting, I have Objection running in a different directory as well. Did you add the framework to your target? Anyhow, thanks for the feedback. I want to make installation as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your framework like so ?

1. In the project navigator, select
   your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries'
   expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select your framework
7. (optional) Drag and drop the added
   framework to the 'Frameworks' group

[See Apple's documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1)

If you have done exactly what I said above then I'm not sure if this is going to work, but I use another method to add frameworks, which is go to your project (The one with the xcodeproj icon), then click on your target.  There, you can add the frameworks you want.

If that doesn't work, then try go to /Library/Frameworks to see if your framework you want is still there.  If it's there and it's still getting that error, try manually adding the framework which is the add other button when you add a framework.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did.
BTW: the Framework I want to use is an external Framework which I downloaded from github and copied into the app directory

Comment: oh. then check this out - http://meandmarkpublishing.blogspot.com/2007/01/linking-external-libraries-and.html & this too should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473515/building-objective-c-app-with-external-framework

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem either. I do not need the copy build phase because my framework is within my app directory (src-> $SRC_ROOT/External/Objection). Further I have added this directory to the frameworks search path..
I have absolutely no idea what's missing :(